# Install kubernetes cluster in devstack

Tags: openstack, devstack

I have installed devstack in my server as per [this](https://ubuntu.com/openstack/install#multi-node-deployment) steps and I was looking for some updated instructions to install kubernates cluster in it. Even though my question is on kubernetes I would like to clarify few points.

1. Is Openstack opensource ? or the opensource version is called devstack. Because I was trying to install a production ready environment but everywhere I see examples to install devstack or the one is few years old.
2. How to Install Openstack not Devstack

And finally can someone please help me with instruction to install kubernetes on devstack as thats the one I could install now and I guess the instructions would be almost similar.

I know there are posts but almost all of them are few years old so a help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping that it is allowed to reference my own work: I wrote a short series of articles about [Kubernetes on Devstack](https://itnext.io/running-a-kubernetes-cluster-on-devstack-533d579bb2f9), both Kubernetes from scratch and using OpenStack Magnum.

The document that you used to install OpenStack describes not Devstack, but Microstack.

OpenStack is 100% open-source, yes. See https://www.openstack.org/.

Devstack is one of the many ways to deploy an OpenStack cloud. Its original purpose is to set up a test environment for OpenStack developers, and not so much to be user-friendly, but it is often used for training or proof-of-concept.

There are many other deployment methods: Microstack (easy but not very flexible), Packstack (requires RHEL or Centos), Tripleo (also requires RHEL or Centos and a bit more powerful hardware), Kolla-Ansible, and the best method for learners in my opinion: [Manual setup](https://docs.openstack.org/wallaby/install/). This list is far from complete.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for the reply. In fact I saw your reference and was going to follow that. Btw thats a great work and thanks again!. But regarding the environment I still have confusion. I am looking for a production ready setup. I see the openstack.org link you shared but where I can find the installation instruction ? Or do you think I need to go for any of these - Packstack or Tripleo ? I assume they are still open source. Let me know if you can help me to find some instructions. I am using Centos 8

Comment: Packstack is not a production environment. For example, it does not allow you to set up redundant controllers. Tripleo is the subscription-free version of Red Hat's OpenStack product and therefore a good solution for production. Everything is open-source. You find Tripleo and other deployment instructions at https://docs.openstack.org/victoria/deploy/.